# How to search for a string INSIDE of entries in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

So I get how to use the .includes option in JavaScript, but I need it to be able to find if a string is even just PART of an entry in an array.  How would this be done?  For example, to see if an array includes the value "Chocolate" in one of its entries, or as PART of one of its entries.  Thanks,

Greg

Here's my code so far:

```js
function filterByWord(arr, flavor){

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].includes(flavor)) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }

}

console.log(filterByWord(originalFlavors, "Chocolate"))
```

Comment: This should work. If the array is `["Vanilla", "Dark Chocolate"]` it will return `"Dark Chocolate"`

Comment: What is the value of `originalFlavors`?

Comment: Yes but I need it to see if it just includes chocolate in an entry.  Like if it has chocolate and dark chocolate and chocolate swirl, I want it to find all 3.

Comment: Yeah Greg, it looks fine per your sought after requirements... Maybe showing the ````originalFlavors```` array will help us.

Comment: originalFlavors is an array with tons of ice cream flavors including versions of chocolate

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the first match. The `return` statement ends the function, which stops the loop.

Use `filter()` to find all matches.

```js
function filterByWord(arr, flavor) {
  return arr.filter(x => x.includes(flavor));
}

const originalFlavors = ["Dark Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Chocolate Swirl", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"];
console.log(filterByWord(originalFlavors, "Chocolate"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar says, you are returning the first match, he already gives an optimized solution using filter, if you are not comfortable with this tool and want to keep the most of your original code I suggest you modify it like this:

```
function filterByWord(arr, flavor){
let filteredWords = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].includes(flavor)) {
        filteredWords.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
return filteredWords;
}
console.log(filterByWord(originalFlavors, "Chocolate"));
```

Notice that my suggestion is creating an empty array that is going to be filled with all the matching words when looping. As I said, Barmar's solution is more optimized but this can work out too and I believe this was what you were trying to attempt.